# Attach to docker hosted PHP / Xdebug on Windows 11 not working

Tags: docker, vscode-extensions, xdebug

I've been working with VS Code and Xdebug 3 for many years with success on a WampServer based setup but I need to move to a docker environment instead. I've set up a working MariaDB/Apache/PHP docker server but fail to get debugging working.

This is the setting in php.ini file

```ini
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.mode=debug
# the default port for Xdebug 3 is 9003, not 9000
xdebug.client_port=9003
# The line below is commented. This is the IP of your host machine, where your IDE is installed.
# We set this IP via XDEBUG_CONFIG environment variable in docker-compose.yml instead.
```

In `docker-compose.yaml` I configured the `XDEBUG_CONFIG` to listen for host.docker.internal:

```yaml
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: client_host=host.docker.internal # This is for XDebug 3. For XDebug 2, we should use remote_host instead of client_host.
    extra_hosts:
         - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Which seems to be picked up by PHP as `phpinfo();` reports

```
xdebug.client_host  host.docker.internal    localhost
xdebug.client_port  9003    9003
```

And yes in VSCode I've set Xdebug to listen to 9003. `launch.json`:

```json
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9003
    }
```

As I'm used with a WampServer setup I've enabled debugging with `Xdebug helper`, yet when I set a breakpoint in VSCode this is not hit.

What else do I need to connect to a PHP Xdebug session running in a Docker container?

Comment: 1) Enable Xdebug log, try to debug and see what it has to say about the attempt. Does it try to connect at all? Is it trying to connect to the right IP:port part etc. 2) I'd suggest you use `xdebug_info()` instead of `phpinfo()` for Xdebug v3 -- it can provide some troubleshooting messages (Diagnostic Log) there + list all the live config values. 3) Can also try with `xdebug.start_with_request=yes` so the Xdebug will try to debug every single request regardless of the "debug me" flag (and remove it later to use your Xdebug helper)